# Angular interceptor 302 response

Tags: angular, interceptor, http-status-code-302

I am adding a http interceptor in an existing Angular 11 app.

We have 2 resquests onload, they work as expected but when I add the interceptor with no logic, just return the same request, one request starts throwing 302 found status.

So, I dont understand how I should fix this or if there is a walk-around.

Thanks for your help

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'; import { HttpInterceptor, HttpEvent, HttpResponse, HttpRequest, HttpHandler } from '@angular/common/http'; import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable() export class MyInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {  intercept(httpRequest: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(httpRequest);   } }
```

Comment: Is there any headers missing or token ?

Comment: Yes, actually I just noticed that I am missing the bearer token, but I still dont understand why it is missing, does the interceptor remove or change the request?  In my code I am not, (I think) because Im just returning the same req return next.handle(httpRequest); isn't it?

Comment: I have found what the problem is :( I added the interceptor to a child module (because I only need it there) and I think it is overwriting the other app's interceptors

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no way to intercept/control requests with the 302 status code in Angular. if you want to take control of the request you have two ways:

1. make a change on the API, instead of returning 302 just return your data and then do the redirection by yourself, for instance, return the page address, and in your code just set the new location like

   window.location.href = apiReturnedURL;
2. use a form for sending data and redirecting:

```
<form ngNoForm [action]="googleSignInUrl" method="post">
               <input type="hidden" name="filed1" [value]="filed1" />
               <input type="hidden" name="filed2" [value]="filed2" />
               <button   type="submit">Sing In</button>
           </form>
```

**Please notice the ngNoForm directive**

Answer (score -2):

I think you missed something.
Please view carefully this article and then check. I hope this will work for you
https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/intro-to-angular-http-interceptors

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "missed something", what did I miss? I have the same as that guide, my problem is that one request is returning 302 and the browser is not catching it

Comment: If all you have is a link it should be a comment not an answer. Or provide details in the answer so if the link stops working the answer is still useful.

Comment: can you provide fiddle example so that I can exactly point out what is going wrong?

Comment: describing and pasting huge text here according to me is not friendly readable that's why I provided complete link but Next time I will try to keep this point in mind